# Proxy error ECONNRESET from localhost with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, proxy

I have a Proxy error: Could not proxy request /users/login from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).

I tried to add "secure": false to my package.json and I also replaced the localhost with 127.0.0.1, I Reset Chrome settings to default, but nothing is working the proxy error is still here. Any help will be welcome

Comment: Did you check CORS header?

Comment: yes I did everything seems fine

Comment: In chrome proxy configuration, there is setting where you can specify url for which chrome will bypass proxy. Can you add "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" there and try again.